# Extract mean from ARMA(p,q) process

Tags: process, time-series, mean

× 19778

Extract mean from an ARMA(p,q) process

mean of an AR(p) process is mean= (intercept)/(1-phi1-phi2-..-phip) ,is this formula the same for an ARMA(p,q) also..?

ARMA(p,q):
Xt= intercept + Phi1 Xt-1 + Phi2 Xt-2 + ...+ Phip Xt-p + Epsilont+ theta1 Epsilont-1 +..+
thetaq Epsilont-q

where phi1,phi2,..,phip are the coefficients of AR part..

more info: I am comparing mean of a time series before an event and after an event..generally one can take a simple mean and compare. but since my data is auto-correlated I want to model the time series before and after so I can compare before and after means .. hence I need to extract the mean from a ARMA(p,q) process.

Thank You in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Questions should be specific and typically include code snippets and explanations of what has been tried already

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the moving average terms do not affect the marginal mean, they only affect the variance.

In comparing the two means, you will also need to adjust the variances because of the autocorrelations.

You are better off fitting an intervention model rather than trying to handle the autocorrelations by hand.